Animated show where a girl is kidnapped by some creature after a fight with her parents
I was a kid when I saw this animated show so I don't remember it in great detail. What I can remember is that there was a girl, I think she was a child, who had a fight with her parents.  After that, late at night, she was kidnapped by some creature. I remember all the things in her room were shaking like there was an earthquake.  I remember I was very scared of it back then.

When/where did you watch it?  Was it new then?  Were there weekly episodes? Or was it a movie?

This sounds like the end of Labyrinth; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EPLxitZJck8

This sounds like the beginning of Labyrinth https://youtu.be/nJ19zSF6Qs8?si=R_YO8Qxeq7cUpbrL

In roughly which year did you watch this? And was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

Okay to answer some of the comments: I don't remember where (what channel was it) I watched it. The animation was 2D and it was I think roughly 2006. It was a movie.

I guess you might be talking about "Coraline" Although "Coraline" is a stop-motion animated film, its visual style can give the impression of a 2D animation in some scenes.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
